# Show Country list in drop-down PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, phpspreadsheet

I am trying to create an excel file using *PHPExcel*. I want to show a country drop-down in one column so that user can choose country and and upload it back with other data.

Now to create a dropdown in excel file, we can use data validation as follows

```
$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getCell('N' . $i)->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType(PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST);
$objValidation->setFormula1('"male,female"');
```

But it has limitation of 256 chars I suppose and country list is certainly greater than this limit. When I create my excel file, drop-down like above work but my country drop-down shows empty drop-down.

I tried with named range as well

```
$objPHPExcel->addNamedRange( 
new PHPExcel_NamedRange(
    'countries', 
    $objPHPExcel->getSheet(1), 
    'A1:A'.($counter-1),
    false,
    NULL
) 
);

$objValidation->setFormula1('countries');
```

Tried these one also

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('=countries');

$objValidation->setFormula1('countries!A1:A'.($counter-1));
```

But it also shows same result. So am I missing something.

Answer (score 2):

```
$objValidation->setFormula1('worksheetName!$A$1:$A$3');
```

Should work, as described in the [PHPExcel Docs](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#setting-data-validation-on-a-cell) and demonstrated in examples [15datavalidation.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/15datavalidation.php) and [15datavalidation-xls.php](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/15datavalidation-xls.php) in the `Examples` folder

As should using a named range, and there is an Example of this in [file `39dropdown.php` in the Examples folder](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/1.8/Examples/39dropdown.php) using continents and countries

```
$objPHPExcel->addNamedRange(
    new PHPExcel_NamedRange(
        'Continents', 
        $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet(), $continentColumn . '1:' . $continentColumn . ($key+1)
    )
);


$objValidation = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
    ->getCell('B1')
    ->getDataValidation();
$objValidation->setType( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::TYPE_LIST )
    ->setErrorStyle( PHPExcel_Cell_DataValidation::STYLE_INFORMATION )
    ->setAllowBlank(false)
    ->setShowInputMessage(true)
    ->setShowErrorMessage(true)
    ->setShowDropDown(true)
    ->setErrorTitle('Input error')
    ->setError('Continent is not in the list.')
    ->setPromptTitle('Pick from the list')
    ->setPrompt('Please pick a continent from the drop-down list.')
    ->setFormula1('=Continents');
```

All of these examples work without issue (although linked dropdowns don't work with the Excel5 Writer.

All I can suggest is to make sure that you're referencing the correct cell range on the correct worksheet in your formula